# How to use alias column in whereIn with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

here is my code. I am trying to get new list of A items in order to loop on.

```
 $allowed_a = \App\NewA::select('name')->get()->pluck('name');        
 $a = App\A::selectRaw("replace(unaccent(trim(name)), ' ', '') AS newname, name")
             ->whereIn('newname', $allowed_a)->get();
```

But I am getting **Undefined column** *'newname'*.
How can I fix it please?
thanks

Comment: I think the whereIn can't access data from other queries, so It's not possible to access your alias

Comment: Ok, do you have any trick for me?

Comment: I tried and I am getting error near of one array items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve something equivalent using:

```
$allowed_a = \App\NewA;
\App\A::selectRaw('replace(unaccent(trim(name)) as newname')
      ->whereRaw('replace(unaccent(trim(name)) IN ("'.implode('","', $allowed_a).'")')
      ->get()
```

Comment: I think we are on the way. How can I fix names with single quote? they are causing error

Comment: @Cutis Yah, I just did some ```tinker```ing. Try the above after edits.

Comment: @Cutis Also if you dont care about receiving the newname with replace, etc, I would drop the selectRaw, to save your DB a bit of effort, and just select name.

Comment: @Cutis No problem!

Comment: Of course, no problem, I am working to find the right syntax

Comment: @Cutis still not working for you? I had it working on my local. What error you getting?

Comment: your code is great! I am using Postgresql and I get something like "Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at end of input LINE 1: " near one item of array, so I am trying to fix it.

Comment: @Cutis I was testing with MySql 8... Must be the issue

Comment: Yuh! I think I need to find another way to deal with this task. I will accept your answer! thanks

Comment: you miss the other param of replce function.

Comment: @Cutis Bahhhhh! sry, mysql did not have the unaccent, so I was testing using only trim(name). Sorry!