# Laravel whereIn array Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5, eloquent

Searching a trick for this issue [How to use alias column in whereIn with Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62953660/how-to-use-alias-column-in-wherein-with-laravel), I am trying:

```
$allowed_a = \App\NewA::select('name')->get()->pluck('name');        
$a = App\A::whereRaw("replace(unaccent(trim(name)), ' ', '') IN ?", $allowed_a)->get();
```

But I am getting **Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined**, because I need so many

> ?

as many elements in the table, but the I do not know the array lenght.
How to deal with this?
Thanks

Comment: Hello, did You solv it?